# c++/ looking for documentation (like dirent.h) on directories and files?

Tags: c++, documentation, ubuntu-10.04, dirent.h

I'm looking for documentation on C++ code for file and directory implementation into C++ programs.

I like going to cplusplus.com because of the documents and examples they have, but I can't find documentation on dirent.h, I'm not even sure it's all that great.

I'm looking to have a program able to see inside a directory, meaning obtaining a list of the files and sub-directories within, plus being able to get the modify/creation date of such things. I program in Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to terminal, type `man dirent`, press enter and read it. If your distribution didn't install manpages for some reason, it won't be available. But in this case you can google it.